# System solution in [0,1]

Tags: python, math, equation, constraint-programming

I have a system of equation like bellow:

```
"L3 + L4 + S5 + S12 + L1 + D4 + L8 + S3 + L7 + D8 + D5 + L5 == 1",
"L4 + D9 + S5 + L1 + D16 + L8 + L6 + S8 + L7 + D8 == 1",
"L4 + L1 + D16 + S60 + L2 == 1",
"L3 + D12 + L1 + S9 + S3 + D5 + S105 + L2 + L7 + D28 + L5 == 1",
"S11 + L3 + S72 + D10 + D72 + D9 + S5 + D16 + S9 + S60 + L6 + S105 + L2 + L8 + D5 == 1",
"L3 + S60 + L2 + L4 == 1",
"D72 + L6 + S105 + L7 + D28 + L5 == 1",
"S72 + D72 + L8 + L6 + L5 == 1",
"D4 + S12 + S11 + D10 == 1",
"D12 + D10 + S9 + S8 + D8 + S12 == 1",
"S11 + D12 + S72 + D9 + D4 + S3 + S8 + D28 == 1",
"S11 + D12 + D10 + D72 + D9 + D28 + S72 + S5 + S12 + D4 + D16 + S9 + S3 + S60 + S8 + S105 + D8 + D5 == 1"
```

and i need all possible solutions where solution are in [0 or 1]
And solution would be like :
S1 = [L3,D12, S9]
S2 = [L4, D72, S8] solution should take on element from L, D and S.
I need to make this code on python, and I was trying to model the equation system as matrix :
M_L*L + M_D*D + M_S*S = Ones
but dont have a hint for coding that.
Can somebody help please ?

I tried loops and it was not easy to implement. I tried as well the library sympy:
here is my code
the issue is that i dont have combination of solution and should add constraint

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, S3, S5, S8, S9, S11, S12, S60, S72, S105, D4, D5, D8, D9, D10, D12, D16, D28, D72 = symbols('L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 S3 S5 S8 S9 S11 S12 S60 S72 S105 D4 D5 D8 D9 D10 D12 D16 D28 D72', boolean=True)


eq1 = Eq(L3 + L4 + S5 + S12 + L1 + D4 + L8 + S3 + L7 + D8 + D5 + L5, 1)
eq2 = Eq(L4 + D9 + S5 + L1 + D16 + L8 + L6 + S8 + L7 + D8, 1)
eq3 = Eq(L4 + L1 + D16 + S60 + L2, 1)
eq4 = Eq(L3 + D12 + L1 + S9 + S3 + D5 + S105 + L2 + L7 + D28 + L5, 1)
eq5 = Eq(S11 + L3 + S72 + D10 + D72 + D9 + S5 + D16 + S9 + S60 + L6 + S105 + L2 + L8 + D5, 1)
eq6 = Eq(L3 + S60 + L2 + L4, 1)
eq7 = Eq(D72 + L6 + S105 + L7 + D28 + L5, 1)
eq8 = Eq(S72 + D72 + L8 + L6 + L5, 1)
eq9 = Eq(D4 + S12 + S11 + D10, 1)
eq10 = Eq(D12 + D10 + S9 + S8 + D8 + S12, 1)
eq11 = Eq(S11 + D12 + S72 + D9 + D4 + S3 + S8 + D28, 1)
eq12 = Eq(S11 + D12 + D10 + D72 + D9 + D28 + S72 + S5 + S12 + D4 + D16 + S9 + S3 + S60 + S8 + S105 + D8 + D5, 1)

solution = solve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11, eq12))

print(solution)
```

Comment: ABAT, this appears to be a case of so-called integer programming, perhaps the subcategory called 0-1 programming. My advice is to work with a dedicated solver package such as GLPK (there are many others). Web searches for those terms will bring up a lot of resources.

Comment: Could you [edit]() your question and state with more detail what you mean by *"solution would be like : S1 = [L3,D12, S9] S2 = [L4, D72, S8] solution should take on element from L, D and S"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [z3 smt solver](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3). A `BitVec` of length `1` can hold the values 0 and 1.

## Bit vectors of length 1

The following example code uses bitvectors of length 1. If I understand correctly, the sums will be done modulo 2.

```py
from z3 import Solver, BitVec, sat, Or

s = Solver()

param = [BitVec(name, 1) for name in
         'L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 S3 S5 S8 S9 S11 S12 S60 S72 S105 D4 D5 D8 D9 D10 D12 D16 D28 D72'.split()]
L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, S3, S5, S8, S9, S11, S12, S60, S72, S105, D4, D5, D8, D9, D10, D12, D16, D28, D72 = param

s.add(L3 + L4 + S5 + S12 + L1 + D4 + L8 + S3 + L7 + D8 + D5 + L5 == 1)
s.add(L4 + D9 + S5 + L1 + D16 + L8 + L6 + S8 + L7 + D8 == 1)
s.add(L4 + L1 + D16 + S60 + L2 == 1)
s.add(L3 + D12 + L1 + S9 + S3 + D5 + S105 + L2 + L7 + D28 + L5 == 1)
s.add(S11 + L3 + S72 + D10 + D72 + D9 + S5 + D16 + S9 + S60 + L6 + S105 + L2 + L8 + D5 == 1)
s.add(L3 + S60 + L2 + L4 == 1)
s.add(D72 + L6 + S105 + L7 + D28 + L5 == 1)
s.add(S72 + D72 + L8 + L6 + L5 == 1)
s.add(D4 + S12 + S11 + D10 == 1)
s.add(D12 + D10 + S9 + S8 + D8 + S12 == 1)
s.add(S11 + D12 + S72 + D9 + D4 + S3 + S8 + D28 == 1)
s.add(S11 + D12 + D10 + D72 + D9 + D28 + S72 + S5 + S12 + D4 + D16 + S9 + S3 + S60 + S8 + S105 + D8 + D5 == 1)
res = s.check()
count = 0
while res == sat:
    count += 1
    M = s.model()
    sol = [M[p] for p in param]
    # print(count, sol)
    print(count, ", ".join([f"{p}:{M[p]}" for p in param]))
    s.add(Or([p != M[p] for p in param]))
    res = s.check()
```

The output starts with

```py
1 L1:0, L2:0, L3:0, L4:0, L5:0, L6:0, L7:0, L8:1, S3:0, S5:1, S8:1, S9:1, S11:0, S12:1, S60:1, S72:1, S105:1, D4:0, D5:0, D8:0, D9:0, D10:0, D12:0, D16:0, D28:1, D72:1
2 L1:1, L2:1, L3:1, L4:1, L5:1, L6:1, L7:1, L8:1, S3:1, S5:0, S8:0, S9:0, S11:1, S12:0, S60:0, S72:0, S105:0, D4:1, D5:1, D8:0, D9:0, D10:1, D12:0, D16:0, D28:0, D72:0
3 L1:1, L2:1, L3:1, L4:1, L5:1, L6:1, L7:0, L8:0, S3:1, S5:0, S8:0, S9:0, S11:1, S12:0, S60:0, S72:1, S105:0, D4:1, D5:1, D8:0, D9:0, D10:1, D12:0, D16:0, D28:1, D72:0
4 L1:1, L2:0, L3:1, L4:0, L5:0, L6:0, L7:0, L8:0, S3:1, S5:0, S8:0, S9:0, S11:1, S12:0, S60:0, S72:1, S105:0, D4:1, D5:1, D8:0, D9:0, D10:1, D12:0, D16:0, D28:1, D72:0
5 L1:1, L2:0, L3:1, L4:0, L5:0, L6:0, L7:0, L8:0, S3:0, S5:1, S8:0, S9:0, S11:1, S12:0, S60:0, S72:0, S105:0, D4:1, D5:1, D8:0, D9:1, D10:1, D12:0, D16:0, D28:0, D72:1
...
```

## Bit vectors of length 8 with 0 or 1 constraint

If you change it to bit vectors of length 8, and add a constraint that each value should be either 0 or 1, no solutions are found. If you'd limit the equations to e.g. the first 8, 3 solutions are found.

```py
from z3 import Solver, BitVec, sat, Or, And

s = Solver()

param = [BitVec(name, 8) for name in
         'L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 S3 S5 S8 S9 S11 S12 S60 S72 S105 D4 D5 D8 D9 D10 D12 D16 D28 D72'.split()]
L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, S3, S5, S8, S9, S11, S12, S60, S72, S105, D4, D5, D8, D9, D10, D12, D16, D28, D72 = param
L = [p for p in param if str(p).startswith('L')]
S = [p for p in param if str(p).startswith('S')]
D = [p for p in param if str(p).startswith('D')]

s.add(And([And(p >= 0, p <= 1) for p in param]))
eqs = [L3 + L4 + S5 + S12 + L1 + D4 + L8 + S3 + L7 + D8 + D5 + L5,
       L3 + D12 + L1 + S9 + S3 + D5 + S105 + L2 + L7 + D28 + L5,
       L4 + D9 + S5 + L1 + D16 + L8 + L6 + S8 + L7 + D8,
       L4 + L1 + D16 + S60 + L2,
       S11 + L3 + S72 + D10 + D72 + D9 + S5 + D16 + S9 + S60 + L6 + S105 + L2 + L8 + D5,
       S72 + D72 + L8 + L6 + L5,
       L3 + S60 + L2 + L4,
       D72 + L6 + S105 + L7 + D28 + L5,
       D4 + S12 + S11 + D10,
       S11 + D12 + D10 + D72 + D9 + D28 + S72 + S5 + S12 + D4 + D16 + S9 + S3 + S60 + S8 + S105 + D8 + D5,
       D12 + D10 + S9 + S8 + D8 + S12,
       S11 + D12 + S72 + D9 + D4 + S3 + S8 + D28]
s.add(And([eq == 1 for eq in eqs]))
res = s.check()
count = 0
while res == sat:
    count += 1
    M = s.model()
    sol = [M[p] for p in param]
    if count % 100 == 0 or count <= 10:
        print(count, ", ".join([f"{p}:{M[p]}" for p in param]))
    s.add(Or([p != M[p] for p in param]))
    res = s.check()
print(f"{count} solutions found")
```

Output:

```
0 Solutions found
```

Comment: I have adjusted the equations and now i found solution for that, thank you for the hint @bterwijn

Answer (score 0):

You do find solutions right, it maybe is clearer if you print the solution like this:

```
for var, eq in solution.items():
    print(var,' = ',eq)
```

which gives:

```
D10  =  L4/2 - L6/2 - L7/2 - S105/2 - S11/2 - S12/2 + S3/2 + S60/2 + S72/2 - S9/2 + 1/2
D12  =  L3/2 + L4/2 + L6/2 + L7 + S105/2 - S3/2 + S5/2 - S72 - S8/2 - S9/2
D16  =  L3 + L5 + L6 + L7 + L8 - S60 - 1
D28  =  -L7 + L8 - S105 + S72
D4  =  -L4/2 + L6/2 + L7/2 + S105/2 - S11/2 - S12/2 - S3/2 - S60/2 - S72/2 + S9/2 + 1/2
D5  =  -L3/2 + L4/2 + L6/2 - S105/2 - S3/2 - S5/2 + S8/2 - S9/2 - 1
D72  =  -L5 - L6 - L8 - S72 + 1
D8  =  -L3/2 - L4 - L7/2 + S11/2 - S12/2 - S5/2 - S60/2 + S72/2 - S8/2 + 1/2
D9  =  -L3/2 - L6 - L7/2 - L8 - S11/2 + S12/2 - S5/2 + S60/2 - S72/2 - S8/2 + 1/2
L1  =  -L5 - L6 - L7 - L8 + S60 + 1
L2  =  -L3 - L4 - S60 + 1
```

You just find many solutions as the solution is underdetermined. If you want to add additional constraints, that variables are either 0 or 1, then you want to use a Binary Linear Programming or a Integer Linear Programming solver instead. Maybe have a look at:

https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/

Comment: I am adding more details maybe this could help :
my two constraint are : 
Variables should be neither equal to 0 or 1
solution is a set of arrays that contain one D variable , one S variable and on L variable.
Example : Solution = {S1 = [D10, S105, L4], S2 = [D12, S3, L8]... etc }

Comment: Do not add details in comments, [add them to your post](/help/how-to-ask),